# 'C:\Users\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: batch-file, makefile, command, external, internal

i have this error in building in atmel studio 6 :
C:\Program Files\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.1\shellUtils\make.exe all 
'C:\Users\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

The entire string you show needs to be in quotes.  Unfortunately you did not show any code... so we are left to guess. 1. It may appear as a string where it is used. 2. More likely you have something like this:

```
set SomeVariable=C:\Program Files\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.1\shellUtils\make.exe
```

Typically you would leave that as it is (or better yet; use the quotes as I have shown below so you are certain there only trailing spaces if you intend to have them) and do the quoting when the variable is used because you may not always want those quotes.  For example, the first line below defines the string; the second line would display it; and the third line would execute it.  The 4th line would be used to pass the string to a subroutine.

```
set "SomeVariable=C:\Program Files\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.1\shellUtils\make.exe"
echo(%SomeVariable%
"%SomeVariable%"
call Subroutine "%SomeVariable%"
```

Ahhhh... Based on the Print screen supplied later I think you need to use quotes like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.1\shellUtils\make.exe" all
```

Comment: a print screen for the error https://www.dropbox.com/s/4s1ho454p1kcusv/atmel%20studio%20erorr.jpg

Comment: and this the code#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void)
{
 DDRB = 0b00000001 ;
    while(1)
    {
       
   PORTB = 0b00000001 ;
   _delay_ms(500);
   PORTB = 0b00000000 ;
    }
}

Comment: See my edited response based on your print screen.  I will leave the original answer for others... although the original answer does not apply to your make file.

Comment: how can i modify this ??

Comment: I am not familiar with Atmel Studio.  The string in question is probably somewhere in your ASF project.

Comment: thank u for ur interaction with me , i am grateful for ur appreciation.