# Windows 7 MySQL error: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mysql, window

I am running MySQL inside a windows7.
In machine 1 MySql was installed by XAMPP packge.
In machine 2 I Installed MySQL using default configuration for windows install from MySQL site. That means, it was installed in Program Files (x86)\MySQL.

This code works good for machine 1:

```
$command ="C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump -u root --add-drop-database --databases DB_TESTE>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\DB_TESTE.sql";
echo shell_exec($command);
```

This code not works for machine 2:

```
$command ="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD --add-drop-database --databases DB_TESTE > C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\dumpbymysql\\DB_TESTE.sql";
echo shell_exec($command);
```

For the machine 2 I have this error in the scree:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I think it is related to space between Program and Files folder name. I've tried lot differents ways to use double quote or sigle qoute without sucess. I have foun this post but not solved my issue ['C:\Users\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164728/c-users-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progra).

Any idea in how to solve this? Maybe setting environment variables could solve the problem?

Comment: You could try to use the good old DOS 8.3 file name format, so try something like $command ="C:\\Progra~1 \\MySQL..."

Comment: Or escape your spaces.

Comment: Hi Cristian, I will try the first one, first. So, windows has 2 directories that stars with the same name Program Files and Program Files (x86). So how could I call the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just found the solution. So to escape the space, I did use `^`:

```
$command ="C:\\Program^ Files^ ^(x86)\\MySQL\\mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD --add-drop-database --databases DB_TESTE > C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\dumpbymysql\\DB_TESTE.sql";
    echo shell_exec($command);
```

This is the post https://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks

Answer (score 0):

Try to also quote the path, like this:

```
$command =""C:\\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\\mysqldump" ... "
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fix the escaping in the command. Try:

```
$command ="C:\\Program\ Files\ \(x86\)\\MySQL\\mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD --add-drop-database --databases DB_TESTE > C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\dumpbymysql\\DB_TESTE.sql";
```

The reason you have all those double slashes in there in the first command is that they need to be escaped to be treated as normal characters in the path, otherwise it will just be treated as escaping the next character (which isn't what you want if it isn't a special character). The double-quote marks allow this escaping to happen and when the command is interpreted, "\" turns into "\" and "\ " will turn into " ".

When you tried to change to single-quotes, all that happened was the escape characters were treated as literal characters, but the space was still being treated as a delimiter to mark the end of the command, which was not what you wanted.

Comment: I missed escaping one space, I updated it, can you try again?